# Efecto scroll en una pagina web

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Estoy haciendo una pagina web que me permita tener unas secciones que se muestren horizontalmente y el resto verticalmente cuando haga scroll hacia abajo sin embargo he intentado de varias formas pero no me a funcionado. les dejo el código que tengo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Página con Scroll Horizontal y Vertical</title>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Deshabilita el desplazamiento horizontal de la ventana del navegador */
  }

  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .scroll-content {
    display: flex;
    /* Ancho total igual al ancho de cada imagen multiplicado por el número total de imágenes */
    width: auto; /* Establecido como auto para permitir que se ajuste dinámicamente */
    transition: transform 0.3s ease; /* Animación de transición para suavizar el desplazamiento horizontal */
  }

  .image {
    width: 100vw; /* Cada imagen ocupa toda la anchura de la ventana */
    height: 100vh; /* Cada imagen ocupa toda la altura de la ventana */
    background-color: #ddd;
    border: 1px solid #999;
  }

  .section {
    height: 100vh; /* Cada sección vertical ocupa toda la altura de la ventana */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="scroll-content">
        <!-- Sección con desplazamiento horizontal -->
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <!-- Añade más imágenes según sea necesario -->
    </div>
    <!-- Secciones con desplazamiento vertical -->
    <div class="section">
        <h2>Otra Sección Vertical</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed nec nisi ligula. In vehicula metus felis, nec tincidunt lorem hendrerit vel. Vivamus rutrum consequat velit. Ut quis lorem et nisi maximus consectetur.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <h2>Otra Sección Vertical</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed nec nisi ligula. In vehicula metus felis, nec tincidunt lorem hendrerit vel. Vivamus rutrum consequat velit. Ut quis lorem et nisi maximus consectetur.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Añade más secciones verticales según sea necesario -->
</div>

<script>
// Variable para rastrear el estado del desplazamiento horizontal
let scrollingHorizontal = false;

// Detecta el desplazamiento horizontal
window.addEventListener('wheel', (e)=> {
    // Si el desplazamiento es hacia abajo y no hay un desplazamiento horizontal actualmente
    if (e.deltaY > 0 && !scrollingHorizontal) {
        // Calcula la cantidad de desplazamiento horizontal
        const scrollAmount = e.deltaY * 2;
        // Aplica la transformación de desplazamiento horizontal
        document.querySelector('.scroll-content').style.transform = `translateX(-${scrollAmount}px)`;
        // Cambia el estado del desplazamiento horizontal
        scrollingHorizontal = true;
    }
});

// Detecta el desplazamiento vertical
window.addEventListener('scroll', (e)=> {
    // Si se ha alcanzado el final de la página y se estaba desplazando horizontalmente
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight && scrollingHorizontal) {
        // Restaura la transformación de desplazamiento horizontal
        document.querySelector('.scroll-content').style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
        // Actualiza el estado del desplazamiento horizontal
        scrollingHorizontal = false;
    }
});

// Calcula el ancho total de todas las imágenes y establece el ancho del contenedor de desplazamiento horizontal
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const totalImageWidth = document.querySelectorAll('.image').length * window.innerWidth;
    document.querySelector('.scroll-content').style.width = totalImageWidth + 'px';

    // Ajusta la altura del contenedor vertical para acomodar todas las imágenes
    const totalImageHeight = document.querySelectorAll('.image').length * window.innerHeight;
    document.querySelector('.container').style.height = totalImageHeight + 'px';
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

por ejemplo en este código tenemos unas secciones de imagines y un texto mas abajo sin embargo la sección de imágenes no se esta mostrando horizontalmente si no que mas bien sigue vertical no entiendo porque ya que le aplique una lógica para esa situación sin embargo persiste

Answer (score 1):

Para conseguir hacer scrool puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera, y luego aplicarlo a las secciones que desees. No es necesario utilizar javascript para ello.
Espero sea lo que estas buscando.

```css
<style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .scroll-content {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      /* Hace que los elementos no se envuelvan */
      gap: 4px;
      /* Espacio entre las imágenes */
      transition: transform 0.3s ease;
      overflow-x: auto;
      /* Permite el desplazamiento horizontal */
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .image {
      flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 4px);
      /* Cada imagen ocupa un tercio del ancho de la ventana menos el espacio entre ellas */
     
      /* Cada imagen ocupa toda la altura de la ventana */
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #ddd;
      border: 1px solid #999;
     
    }

    .section {
      height: 100vh;
      /* Cada sección vertical ocupa toda la altura de la ventana */
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      background-color: #eae4e4;
    }
  </style>
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="scroll-content">
      <!-- Sección con desplazamiento horizontal -->
      <div class="image"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/N2VpxwW/image1.jpg" alt="Imagen 1"></div>
      <div class="image"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/DwJ4Myk/image5.jpg" alt="Imagen 2"></div>
      <div class="image"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/gvBk7gx/image3.jpg" alt="Imagen 3"></div>
      <div class="image"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/DwJ4Myk/image5.jpg" alt="Imagen 4"></div>
      <div class="image"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/gvBk7gx/image3.jpg" alt="Imagen 5"></div>
      <div class="image"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/DwJ4Myk/image5.jpg" alt="Imagen 6"></div>
      <!-- Añade más imágenes según sea necesario -->
    </div>
    <!-- Secciones con desplazamiento vertical -->
    <div class="section">
      <h2>Otra Sección Vertical</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed nec nisi ligula. In vehicula metus felis, nec
        tincidunt lorem hendrerit vel. Vivamus rutrum consequat velit. Ut quis lorem et nisi maximus consectetur.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <h2>Otra Sección Vertical</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed nec nisi ligula. In vehicula metus felis, nec
        tincidunt lorem hendrerit vel. Vivamus rutrum consequat velit. Ut quis lorem et nisi maximus consectetur.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Añade más secciones verticales según sea necesario -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```